# Как сделать фиксированное окно в Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть программа со множеством всплывающих окон, в которые вводятся данные. Встретился с проблемой что при нажатии на основное окно программы исчезает(прячется за главным) окно для ввода данных. Как можно его зафиксировать, чтобы при нажатии на основное окно оно было в фокусе, а второе окно не пряталось за главное окно и просто становилось серым?

### Код

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        self.title("Главное окно") #Заголовок
        w = ((self.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - 450) # ширина экрана
        h = ((self.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - 225) # высота экрана
        self.geometry('900x450+{}+{}'.format(w, h))#Размер
        self.resizable(False, False)#Изменение размера окна
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: sys.exit(0))

        self.btn = ttk.Button(self, text='Открыть', command = lambda: Second_window())
        self.btn.pack()


class Second_window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        self.title("Второе окно") #Заголовок
        w = ((self.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - 450) # ширина экрана
        h = ((self.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - 225) # высота экрана
        self.geometry('380x200+{}+{}'.format(w, h))#Размер
        self.resizable(False, False)#Изменение размера окна

        self.focus_force()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()
```

### Скрины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Главное окно после открытия
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При нажатии на кнопку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Видно что второе окно спряталось за первым
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотелось бы получить второе окно таким как на этом скрине, но чтобы оно было на переднем плане

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick, сейчас добавлю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Скрин и код ниже

### Скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Код

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        self.title("Главное окно") #Заголовок
        w = ((self.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - 450) # ширина экрана
        h = ((self.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - 225) # высота экрана
        self.geometry('900x450+{}+{}'.format(w, h))#Размер
        self.resizable(False, False)#Изменение размера окна
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: sys.exit(0))

        self.btn = ttk.Button(self, text='Открыть', command = lambda: sec())
        self.btn.pack()


class Second_window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        self.title("Второе окно") #Заголовок
        w = ((self.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - 450) # ширина экрана
        h = ((self.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - 225) # высота экрана
        self.geometry('380x200+{}+{}'.format(w, h))#Размер
        self.resizable(False, False)#Изменение размера окна

        self.focus_force()

def sec():
    root = Second_window()#Вызываю класс(окно), которое должно быть поверх других
    root.attributes("-topmost",True)#Реализует активацию режима "Отображение поверх других окон"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()
win.resizable(False, False)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]